# jQuery insert text after </span>

Tags: jquery, innerhtml

I have this html code:

```
<!-- informations -->
        <div class="simple_layer">
            <div class="main_container">
                <!-- user information -->
                <div class="main_content">
                    <span class="label">Account number:</span> ACCOUNT<br>
                    <span class="label">Tariff plan:</span> PLAN<br>
                    <span class="label">End date:</span> 05.23.2019 (371 days)<br>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

I need to replace in each span text so i try this using jQuery:

```
$(".simple_layer .main_content").find("span")[0].innerHTML += ' kk<br>';
```

But it does not replace ACCOUNT with kk i get this output:

```
Account number:kk ACCOUNT
```

And i need to get this:

```
Account number: kk
```

Comment: Can you put a span around the text you want to replace to make targeting it super easy?

Comment: I im rewriting code from old stalker php to jquery and this is html structure that have been open source defined in platform so i would not change html structure because css and html is defined so need only jquuery to to that in example above output

Comment: `<span>` do not change styling in any way.  That should not be an issue.  Without a wrapped element around the specific text, you are going to have to work with replacing text nodes, which is doable, but more involved than just replacing the html of a single element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code, I extract only the spans, append "kk" to those, and append them to a string. Then I replaced the HTML in *main_content* with the new string.

```
var spanCollection = $(".simple_layer .main_content").getElementsByTagName("span");
var newMainContentHTML = "";

for (var i = 0; i < spanCollection.length; i++) {
    newMainContentHTML += spanCollection[i].innerHTML + " kk<br/>";
}

$(".main_content").innerHTML = newMainContentHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your value using a separate span tag. So that we can easily identify that in jquery. Please refer below sample. To replace all the values you have to use for loop and apply same logic inside loop.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){

        $(".simple_layer .main_content").find(".value")[0].innerHTML = ' kk';
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="simple_layer">
            <div class="main_container">
                <!-- user information -->
                <div class="main_content">
                    <span class="label">Account number:</span> <span class="value">ACCOUNT</span><br>
                    <span class="label">Tariff plan:</span> PLAN<br>
                    <span class="label">End date:</span> 05.23.2019 (371 days)<br>
                </div>
            </div>

 </div>

 <p> Click Me </p>
 <div class="output"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery("#account").replaceWith('kk')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="simple_layer">
            <div class="main_container">
                <!-- user information -->
                <div class="main_content">
                  <span class="label">Account number:</span> <span id="account">ACCOUNT</span><br>
                    <span class="label">Tariff plan:</span> PLAN<br>
                    <span class="label">End date:</span> 05.23.2019 (371 days)<br>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Hey you can do the simple way as i did just add a new id and replace text using replacewith() jquery function